# How is the optimal (processor) word size determined? The larger the better?

Tags: operating-system, cpu, cpu-word

My understanding is that the word size of a processor is the number of bits processed by that processor in a single computation. This is (presently) typically 32 or 64 bits. However, my research indicates that the word size was smaller in the past, and has gradually increased over time.

I also understand that the word size is what dictates data transfer through the system bus, instruction size, address sizes, etc.

Given this, how is the optimal word size determined? Is a larger word size always better? If not, why?

I suspect that a larger word size is not always better, since a larger word size *may* mean that one bus cycle (the time it takes to transfer one word across the bus) takes longer?

Thank you.

Comment: 62 bits? never heard of that one. Well, for one thing, a larger word size gives you the ability to access a wider address space and increases the complexity of the instructions to some extent..

Comment: @babon Typo! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, my research indicates that the word size was smaller in the
>   past, and has gradually increased over time.

Yes, very right. While Intel did pioneering work for the 16-bit and 32-bit CPUs (the 8086 and 80386 processors were the first of their kind, respectively), AMD created their AMD64 (a.k.a. x86-64 or simply x64) architecture, an extension over the 32-bit x86 architecture started with the 80386. Intel created a whole new thing, the IA-64 architecture, but nobody actually uses it.

> I suspect that a larger word size is not always better, since a larger
>   word size may mean that one bus cycle (the time it takes to transfer
>   one word across the bus) takes longer?

That's correct under the assumption that your bus is not as wide as the datum you want to transport. Sending a 32-bit datum over a 16-bit bus does indeed take longer. However, transporting a 64-bit datum over a 64-bit bus takes just as long as a 16-bit datum over a 16-bit bus.

Because of that, the word size is equal to the width of the bus. In a Von Neumann machine, there are three buses, so there has been some controversy concerning what to actually define as the word size, but usually, the data bus is meant.

So, the fact that the word size has increased over the years is caused by advancing technology (related: [Moore's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore's_law)). Science has pushed forward and aimed for better, faster CPUs.

Now we have 64-bit CPUs, but with their instruction sets, immediate operands (literals) are treated as 64-bit too. That means, loading, for example, `0x1` into a 64-bit register requires a minimum of 9 bytes (immediate operand + opcode). This is obviously disadvantageous if the architecture doesn't provide a special instruction to load one sign- or zero-extended byte into a 64-bit register. Therefore, there have been ways to improve that, notably the [ARM Thumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Thumb)<sup>1</sup> instruction set, which tries to diminish code size at the cost of increased execution time.

After all, there is no "optimal word size." It depends on the application and the environment. Some programs require speed, some must be small in size.

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't know why it's called "Thumb," perhaps because the instructions are so small they fit in a thimble.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response. I have a question with regards to your last comment - 'After all, there is no "optimal word size." It depends on the application and the environment. Some programs require speed, some must be small in size.'. So although there is no 'optimal word size', *assuming* the bus was wide enough to transport *any* word size one wishes, a larger word size would always be better?

Comment: @handler'shandle You need to make a trade-off. If you had a 128-bit data bus and, you could transport 128-bit at a time. That's fantastic! But the instruction telling the CPU to transport those 128 bits somehow needs to incorporate that data to be sent, which is 128 bits in size. So, either the instruction set designers come up with a method to somehow compress that data or the instruction simply has those 128 bits (16 bytes), which obviously makes it very large. So, the trade-off here is increased speed (large data bus) or decreased size (small data bus).

Comment: @handler'shandle I highly recommend reading about ARM Thumb if you really want to know more. It is all about that trade-off I mentioned.

Comment: So a larger bus size is only better *if* the compression algorithms to compress the instruction size also improve proportionally?

Comment: @handler'shandle Yes, that's pretty much correct. Except that it isn't really compression algorithms but compression *formats*. The immediate operand is converted to an appropriate format, which represents the same value but is smaller in size. Both x86-64 and ARM have those.

Answer (score 1):

> Given this, how is the optimal word size determined?

The word size is determined as part of the processor design. It is not necessarily optimal. In the past word sizes have included 8, 12, 16, 32, 36, and 64 bits. The more bits in the word size, the more complicate the processor is to implement. A 64-bit addition (that includes calculating memory addresses) take 4 times as many comparisons than a 16-bit addition.

> Is a larger word size always better? If not, why?

"640K ought to be enough for anybody."

There was a time when 32-bits (4GB of memory) was thought to be enough to last forever. How long will 64-bits be enough?

Larger word sizes consume more memory and become more complex to implement. There is a tradeoff.

> I suspect that a larger word size is not always better, since a larger word size may mean that one bus cycle (the time it takes to transfer one word across the bus) takes longer?

The bus transfer size can be different from the processor word size. That is often a bottleneck.